# Scala Play JSON parser throws error on simple key name access

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Would anyone please explain why the following happens?

```
scala> import play.api.libs.json._
scala> Json.toJson("""{"basic":"test"}""") // WORKS CORRECTLY
res134: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = "{\"basic\":\"test\"}"    

scala> Json.toJson(""" {"basic":"test"} """) \ "basic" // ??? HOW COME?
res131: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = JsUndefined('basic' is undefined on object: " {\"basic\":\"test\"} ")
```

Many thanks

Comment: `Json.toJson()` does not *create* an object. It turns an object into a JSON string. What I think you're wanting is `Json.parse()`. Once you've `parse`d a JSON string, it's an object, and you can get to the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Json.toJson` renders its argument as a JSON value using an implicitly provided `Writes` instance. If you give it a string, you'll get a `JsString` (typed as a `JsValue`). You want `Json.parse`, which parses its argument:

```
scala> Json.parse("""{"basic":"test"}""") \ "basic"
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = "test"
```

As expected.

And to address your answer (which should be a comment or a new question, by the way), if you give `toJson` a value of some type `A`, it will convert it into a JSON value, assuming that there's an instance of the `Writes` type class in scope for that `A`. For example, the library provides `Writes[String]`, `Writes[Int]`, etc., so you can do the following:

```
scala> Json.prettyPrint(Json.toJson(1))
res11: String = 1

scala> Json.prettyPrint(Json.toJson("a"))
res12: String = "a"

scala> Json.prettyPrint(Json.toJson(List("a", "b")))
res13: String = [ "a", "b" ]
```

You can also create `Writes` instances for your own types (here I'm using Play's ["JSON inception"](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/ScalaJsonInception)):

```
case class Foo(i: Int, s: String)

implicit val fooWrites: Writes[Foo] = Json.writes[Foo]
```

And then:

```
scala> Json.prettyPrint(Json.toJson(Foo(123, "foo")))
res14: String = 
{
  "i" : 123,
  "s" : "foo"
}
```

Using type classes to manage encoding and decoding is an alternative to reflection-based approaches, and it has a lot of advantages (but that's out of the scope of this question).

Answer (score 1):

Turning my comment into an answer:

`Json.toJson()` does not create an object. It turns an object into a JSON string. What I think you're wanting is `Json.parse()`. Once you've `parse`d a JSON string, it's an object, and you can get to the properties.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to both of you. So the following works as expected.

scala> Json.parse("""{"basic":"test"}""") \ "basic"
  res137: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = "test"

I'd still like to understand what Json.toJson does. The docs state "Transform a stream of A to a stream of JsValue". Can anyone point out in what context this can be used?

Comment: `Json.toJson()` does the opposite of `Json.parse()`. Where parse converts a JSON string into an object, toJson converts an object into a JSON string.